# How to create mysql database backup using one file php script (system() is disabled)

Tags: php, mysql, backup

How to create a mysql database backup using one file php script?

system() is disabled.
I have no cpanel account details, from site admin panel I just can read and write php files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it help you

```
<?php
$DBUSER="";
$DBPASSWD="";
$DATABASE="";
$filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y") . ".sql.gz";
$mime = "application/x-gzip";

header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";
passthru( $cmd );
echo ('Proc is OK !');
exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: This helps!Thank you very much!